# Quartz in high availability architecture

Tags: jboss, cluster-computing, quartz-scheduler, high-availability

I have the next application architecture:

Main DB Server -> (replicated) BackUp DB Server

JBoss Cluster 1 (DS is main DB server), JBoss Cluster 2 (DS is bachup DB server)

Both clusters are olways started up. When cluster 1 stop working, all requests will be redirected to cluster 2.

Issue: my application uses Quartz scheduler and triggers are stored in DB. I want to disable quartz jobs on the cluster 2 (or Quartz at all) and enable it when cluster 1 stopped. Does anyone know simple solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to start the quartz nodes in standy mode.  Then you'll need something that calls start() on the proper set of nodes at the proper time.  What this is (that calls start()) will need to be home-brewed.